# Method [validate] does not exist. - Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying "laravel-modules" and "Laravel-permission package". But when run post, it has issue 'Method [validate] does not exist.'. i have added 'use Validator;' but no thing change. In some topics, i remove "use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;" in PermissionController, but it have error

Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

My PermissionController

```
namespace Modules\User\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

use Auth;

//Importing laravel-permission models
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;

use Session;
class PermissionController extends Controller
{
    // use Validator;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware(['auth', 'isAdmin']); //isAdmin middleware lets only users with a //specific permission permission to access these resources
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $permissions = Permission::all(); //Get all permissions

        return view('user::permissions/index')->with('permissions', $permissions);
        // return view('user::index');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $roles = Role::get(); //Get all roles

        return view('user::permissions/create')->with('roles', $roles);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     * @param  Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'name'=>'required|max:40',
        ]);

        $name = $request['name'];
        $permission = new Permission();
        $permission->name = $name;

        $roles = $request['roles'];

        $permission->save();

        if (!empty($request['roles'])) { //If one or more role is selected
            foreach ($roles as $role) {
                $r = Role::where('id', '=', $role)->firstOrFail(); //Match input role to db record

                $permission = Permission::where('name', '=', $name)->first(); //Match input //permission to db record
                $r->givePermissionTo($permission);
            }
        }

        return redirect()->route('permissions.index')
            ->with('flash_message',
             'Permission'. $permission->name.' added!');
    }
}

Route
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web', 'prefix' => 'permissions', 'namespace' => 'Modules\User\Http\Controllers'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'PermissionController@index');
    Route::get('/create', 'PermissionController@create');
    Route::post('/', 'PermissionController@store');

    Route::delete('/', ["as" => "permissions.destroy", "uses" => "PermissionController@destroy"]);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Add back in `use Validator` in your `PermissionController`. Add this right after `use Auth;`. You have currently added this in the wrong place.

Then change your `$this->validate(...)` code to:

```
// validate the input
$validation = Validator::make( $request->all(), [
    'name'=>'required|max:40',
]);

// redirect on validation error
if ( $validation->fails() ) {
    // change below as required
    return \Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors( $validation->messages() );
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, i got it

Comment: I have the dockerized laravel app and somehow on AWS this does not work. I am on  5.4.36. I started seeing this error when I build the docker image in AWS (on alpine Linux).  I did everything - `composer update`, `composer dump-autoload` and verified the version with `php artisan --version`. I am on laravel 5.4.36 in AWS ECS container.  I am getting `BadMethodCallException
Method [validator] does not exist.`

Comment: Please post a new questions with your issue @Andy

Answer (score 1):

I was trying

```
$this->validate($request, [
     'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
]);
```

But in Laravel 5.7 following code did the trick for me

```
$request->validate([
     'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
]);
```